# Casting object to IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

The following is a simplified version of the problem I'm having:

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// list Count = 5 System.Collections.Generic.List<int>

var obj = list as object;
// obj  Count = 5   object {System.Collections.Generic.List<int>}

var enumerable = obj as IEnumerable<object>;
// enumerable   null    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>
```

The comments are the values from the watch window in Visual Studio 2017

However if I enter:

```
obj as IEnumerable<object>
```

in the watch window, I get:

```
obj as IEnumerable<object>  Count = 5   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> {System.Collections.Generic.List<int>}
```

So how come I can cast it in the watch window and it works, but if I do it in the code it evaluates to null?

Comment: The watch window seems to be buggy, since interface covariance doesn't cover boxing of value types.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: It's not just the debugger. The language doesn't support it.

Comment: Seems to me that you're doing something fundamentally wrong. You can go from a List<T> to an IEnumerable<T> directly. You're doing boxing / unboxing and that practice has been abandoned years ago. With good reason.

Comment: Indeed, it is important to never forget that value types are boxed, **not** cast to object. It makes all the difference in all the wrong places. Plus you should not need to do either anyway. Preventing that is what generics are there for.

Comment: @ToniKostelac there is no boxing/unboxing in code sample... What exactly *you* mean when saying "boxing"?

Comment: @ToniKostelac "that practice [boxing] has been abandoned years ago" - Source? Boxing often occurs with enums for example.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The conversion from `int` to `object` is boxing and thus not representation preserving. Thus `IEnumerator<int>.Current` and `IEnumerator<object>.Current` can't share an implementation, which is why the CLR specification doesn't allow such conversions in interface covariance.

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes, but where it is in the sample code? Casting list of integers to `IEnumerable<object>` simply fails without giving any chance for boxing to happen...

Comment: @RyanSearle we don't do it explicitly, it's handled by the framework for us. If you are doing it explicitly chances are you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This cast is forbidden because it'd require boxing.

Comment: This look so wrong. I think my eye are bleeding :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos The only thing I wanted to confirm from Toni Kostelac is whether they use that same meaning of "boxing" as in the C# spec. I've seen it used as "any cast to `object` is boxing". We can argue if actual boxing "happens in the post" because OP wanted it for some reason in they cast to `IEnumerable<object>` or "does not happen in the post" because this cast is forbidden :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I use both definitions interchangeably.

Comment: @ToniKostelac please **do not** use "boxing" as synonym of "cast to object" when you write/speak with others about C#. The only valid usage of word "boxing" in relation to C# is casting value type (like `int`) to `object`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces):

> Variance in generic interfaces is supported for reference types only. Value types do not support variance. For example, `IEnumerable<int>` cannot be implicitly converted to `IEnumerable<object>`, because integers are represented by a value type.

What helps to know here is that the following two things are *very* different operations under the hood:

```
var l = (object) new List<int>();
var i = (object) 42;
```

despite the syntax looking the same. The first line merely treats the list as another type (with some checks whether the cast actually can work), while the second *converts* the integer into an object containing it (boxing). There's a third variant, which calls a conversion operator, and still looks the same. Since the first variant can get away with changing nothing about the object and just interpreting it differently it's vastly cheaper than the second. And I'd guess in this context here the only option that can work for interface covariance.